# curl php same code works fine on ubuntu but not on wamp windows 8

Tags: php, curl

Am not familiar with Php and I have a problem with running this code on windows  curl_php is enabled and there no errors when I execute the code but i have a blank screen while on ubuntu I got a result , I also disabled firewall but still nothing

```
 $username = "myusername";
 $password = "mypasword";  
 $host = "https://myurl";

 $process = curl_init($host);
 curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
 curl_setopt($process, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);
 curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
 curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

 echo curl_exec($process);
```

Comment: So have you tried debugging at all?  What errors are you getting.  What is the curl response?

Comment: `E_DOESNT_WORK` was not found.

Comment: The dreaded "PHP Blank Screen"; that generally indicates that PHP died in some unfriendly way, but you don't have display-errors on. Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to the top of your script and retry (and then, if you can't determine the issue by the error(s) that display, post them here).

Comment: Did you check php.ini file ? like safe_mode etc.

Comment: Make sure php_curl is turned on in your Wamp server, there should be a check next to it. Click on wamp icon in taskbar. PHP -> PHP extensions -> php_curl

Comment: php_curl is enabled 
 display_errors = On
 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');  added 
 and wamp restarted
 but still blank screen and when I var_dump(curl_exec($process)) it return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to disable ssl verifying (yep, it uses https =) )

Code:

```
<?php 

$username = "myusername"; 
$password = "mypassword"; 
$url = "https://myurl"; 

$process = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

echo curl_exec($process);

curl_close($process);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug. Add the following code to beginning of php file right after `<?php` (on new line):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

And refresh your page. You wil probably see an error if it exists;

If not, add the following after last `curl_setopt` call:

```
echo 'errno: ', curl_errno($process), ', error: ', curl_error($process), "\n";
```

You will probably see an error.

After that we can try to help you to solve the problem;

Maybe there's a redirect to another page, and your windows php installation uses open_basedir restriction. Or maybe something else =)